# instafeed.js stopped working after Instagram API change?

Tags: asp.net, instagram-api, instafeedjs

I have been using instafeed.js for two months and now I see that it doesn't show any Instagram pictures anymore (from the account). Then I read on the Instagram Developers page that there were changes made to the API, so is there anybody who had this problem with the instafeed.js and found a solution?

Comment: did you find the solution to this? If so can you post it? Thanks

Comment: I fixed mine by just re-registering the accounts and getting a new userid and access token!